# How could the "Riemann mapping group" be a group?

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory

Here is the definition of Riemann mapping group:
A set of injective holomorphic functions from a closed unit disk 
$f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ which is holomorphic on the interior and smooth on boundary, normalized by the condition $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$.

How to define the group multiplication?

There's another story that this group is isomorphic to the group $\mathrm{Diff}_+(S^1)/\mathrm{Rot}(S^1)$, which is a conformal  transformation group in physics.

For $f:D\rightarrow D$, by Schwarz lemma, $f(z)=az$ for some $a\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|a|=1$. We can then write $f=e^{i\theta}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Rot}(S^1)$. But I don't know the detail about the general $f$.

I saw it at [Bartlett's comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12022/geometric-visual-interpretation-of-virasoro-algebra#comment732793_192284).
And I guess the  [Kirillov's paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01078025) he mentioned is the origin.

Comment: The comments on the linked post start saying that this is the "quotient group $\mathrm{Diff}(S^1)/\mathrm{Rot}(S^1)$". But in $S^1$ the group of rotations is not normal in the diffeomorphism group. Therefore I would seriously doubt about any assertion by this user. I don't see any natural group law on the set you mention (composition is ill-defined, and pointwise multiplication would not preserve injectivity).

Comment: The only reasonable thing to try without further information is pointwise multiplication. This does give you a new holomorphic function on the disk and it preserves the normalization conditions. However inverses and the identity are not included and injectivity is not preserved. Setting $f(0)=1$ would fix the inverses but not the injectivity.

Comment: Kirilov's paper does not state that this is a group. The notation $\mathrm{Diff}_+(S^1)/\mathrm{Rot}(S^1)$ seem to be understood as the orbits for the action of $\mathrm{Rot}(S^1)$ on $\mathrm{Diff}_+(S^1)$, which seems to have the structure of a manifold in Kirilov's paper, but not of a group.

Comment: There is a key comment by Barlett down below the one you quoted, "It is a while since I thought about this and I hope I haven't confused myself". At the very least, by calling this object a "group" confusion has indeed occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, $\text{Diff}_+(S^1) / \text{Rot}(S^1)$ is not a group. To see this, note that $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$ is a subgroup of $\text{Diff}_+(S^1)$: The homomorphism $\varphi: \text{SL}(2, \mathbb R) \rightarrow \text{Diff}_+(S^1)$ given by
$$\varphi(A)(x,y) = \frac{A(x,y)}{\Vert A(x, y) \Vert}$$
is injective.

Now, the subgroup $\text{Rot}(S^1)$ is actually isomorphic to the subgroup $\text{SO}(2, \mathbb R)$ of $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$ in an obvious way. But $\text{SO}(2, \mathbb R)$ not even normal in $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$ (trial and error will give you a counterexample), so it is also not normal in $\text{Diff}_+(S^1)$. Hence, neither the "Riemann mapping group" nor $\text{Diff}_+(S^1)/\text{Rot}(S^1)$ is a group.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what the meaning of the word "is" is. As is, the space $S$ of holomorphic maps in your question is only a topological space (it has several natural topologies, I will use the uniform topology, for concreteness). [A side issue is that you did not specify what "smooth" means, I assume that it means $C^\infty$.]

One can meaningfully ask if this space is homeomorphic to a topological group, since we are not given a binary operation on $S$. This question has positive answer. To prove this, one first observes (using the Riemann mapping theorem plus Caratheodori's extension theorem) that $S$ is homeomorphic to the quotient space $Diff_+(S^1)/PSL(2,R)$, where $Diff_+(S^1)$ is the space of orientation-preserving smooth diffeomorphisms of $S^1$. The group  $PSL(2,R)$ acts simply transitively on the set of positively oriented triples of distinct points on $S^1$. Therefore, fixing three distinct points $t_1, t_2, t_3\in S^1$, one sees that $Diff_+(S^1)/PSL(2,R)$ is homeomorphic to the subspace $G$ of  $Diff_+(S^1)$ fixing the set $\{t_1, t_2, t_3\}$ pointwise.    Lastly, once we equip $G$ with the binary operation of composition, one can easily verify that $G$ is indeed a topological group. Thus, $S$ is homeomorphic to a topological group. Whether this helps you or not, I have no idea.